# About LINQ and LAMBDA Chain usage

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to understand how Linq chain or lambda chain is working but I couldn't get it. I wrote a sample code below. I can actually run the code with long way like that but I want to learn the other way. I used AWS SDK for the code. I'm trying to do single line code that is managed exactly the same thing while using lambda chain. There is a "_dict" variable for what I want to get from lambda Chain. I must use multiple "GroupBy"s and Select commands for "reservedList" variable but how can I do that?

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> _dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
//Dict<AvailabilityZone, Dict<InstanceType, Count>>

var reservedList = _ec2Client.DescribeReservedInstances(new DescribeReservedInstancesRequest { }).ReservedInstances
                    .GroupBy(q => q.AvailabilityZone);
foreach (var _availabilityZoneItems in reservedList)
{
    if (!_dict.ContainsKey(_availabilityZoneItems.Key))
        _dict.Add(_availabilityZoneItems.Key, new Dictionary<string, int>());
    var typeGroup = _availabilityZoneItems.GroupBy(q => q.InstanceType);
    foreach (var _type in typeGroup)
    {
        var selectionCount = _type.Where(q => q.State == ReservedInstanceState.Active).Sum(q=>q.InstanceCount);
        _dict[_availabilityZoneItems.Key].Add(_type.Key, selectionCount);
    }
}
```

Trying to do something like

```
var reservedList = var reservedList = _ec2Client.DescribeReservedInstances(new DescribeReservedInstancesRequest { }).ReservedInstances
                .GroupBy(q => q.AvailabilityZone)...
                .GroupBy(q => q.InstanceType)
               ....Select...Where..Count...
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to use lamda all the way?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I want to do something like that.

var reservedList = _ec2Client.DescribeReservedInstances(new DescribeReservedInstancesRequest { }).ReservedInstances
                .GroupBy(q => q.AvailabilityZone).GroupBy(q=>q.InstanceType).Select(.....);

But unfortunately could not manage it.

Comment: You can always cast the `IEnumerable<>`s with `.ToList()` and use `.ForEach(x => ...)` (or write a `ForEach` extension for `IEnumerable<>`) to replace the loops, but I would advise against that (search for LINQ ForEach vs loop).

Comment: Should `_availabilityZoneItems` be `_availabilityZone`?  If not where does it come from.

Comment: Yes, i changed the code. Right now, its correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `Enumerable.SelectMany()` This will flatten lists inside a list..

Something like: *(untested/incomplete yet)*

```
var typeGroup = _ec2Client
    .DescribeReservedInstances(new DescribeReservedInstancesRequest {})
    .ReservedInstances.GroupBy(q => q.AvailabilityZone)
    .SelectMany(availabilityZone => 
        availabilityZone
            .GroupBy(q => q.InstanceType)
            .Select(type => new 
            { 
                AvailabilityZone = availabilityZone, 
                Type = type
            }));

foreach (var _type in typeGroup)
{
    var selectionCount = _type.Type.Where(q => q.State == ReservedInstanceState.Active).Count();

    _dict[_type.AvailabilityZoneItems.Key][_type.Type.Key] = selectionCount; 
}
```

Maybe this points you into the right direction. I normally would use Linq for this..

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along these lines

```
_ec2Client.DescribeReservedInstances(new DescribeReservedInstancesRequest()).ReservedInstances
          .GroupBy(q => q.AvailabilityZone)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach (_availabilityZoneItems => {
               _availabilityZoneItems.GroupBy(q => q.InstanceType)
                                     .ToList()
                                     .ForEach(_type => {
                                          _dict[_availabilityZoneItems.Key][_type.Key] = _type.Where(q => q.State == ReservedInstanceState.Active).Count();
                                     });
           });
```

This is untested